# How to select each 20 files from different directories, Python?

Tags: python

There are some directory: `directory` with subdirectories: `QWER`, `TYUI`, etc. In `QWER`, `TYUI`, etc there are files, for example, 1.log, 2.log, etc.
I need process those .log files with 20 threads. Before that, I need to select 20 .log files and process one file in one thread, is it correct? How to select 20 files from directories `QWER`, `TYUI` etc, if there may be less than 20 files per directory or more than 20 files?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried so far? Can you show your current code? Do you have no preference for selecting 20 files?

Comment: I'd tried to append all file paths to list and then take each 20 list elements. I can not share my code, unfortunately. 20 is not necessary. It can be variable

Comment: show us a pseudo code of your current algorithm. If you just want to pick a set of 20 files randomly, the job to be done is far too simple than otherwise. However, do you care to keep a record/archive of what has been fetched? Do you want to flush after reading "the 20 or the 100"? What will happen if the code reads these files again randomly (duplicates)? Answers to these will define your path forward. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Now I append paths of all files in list, than I take slices of 20 items in this list. And then I process it. @Mitchell van Zuylen gives way how to open 20 files only if directory has 20 or more files. But if I have 5 directories for 4 files in each other, my way is good to take all 20 files at once. I'm sure that my way isn't the best practice and I'm searching for good one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.chdir('directory')
# Get the current directory, and for each file in the current directory get at most 20 files
files = [ os.listdir(x)[:20] for x in os.listdir('.')]
```